# How to merge an array of hashes overriding by the latest?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

As per @choroba I tried the following code:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @arrayofhashes = [
    {
        'a' => 4,
        'b' => 3
    },
    {
        'c' => 5,
        'a' => 2
    }

];

my %merged;
@merged{ keys %$_ } = values %$_ for @arrayofhashes;

print Dumper \%merged;
```

That is supposed to dump:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => 2,
          'b' => 3,
          'c' => 5,
        };
```

But is instead failing with:

> "Not a HASH reference"

Thanks again.

Comment: `@arrayofhashes` contains only one element, a reference to an array. You have an AoAoH rather than an AoH. Don't use `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
my %merged;
@merged{ keys %$_ } = values %$_ for @array;
```

For deeper hashes, see [Hash::Merge](http://p3rl.org/Hash::Merge).

**Update:** in your case, your array contains just a single element, an array reference. So you need

```
@merged{ keys %$_ } = values %$_ for @{ $array[0] };
```

instead. Or better, drop the unnecessary level:

```
my @arrayofhashes = (  # <-- Round bracket!
    {
        'a' => 4,
        'b' => 3
    },
    {
        'c' => 5,
        'a' => 2
    }
);
```

Comment: But it's giving me a "Not a HASH reference" error though.

Comment: So the array contains something that's not a hash reference.

Comment: I updated my original question with my code.

Comment: See @ikegami's comment above.

Comment: Hello, have couple of question. Sent to you on Telegram. May you answer? Thanks